# View not found in MVC4 / ASP.net 4.5 hybrid application

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4

Our main site is ASP.net 4.5 and uses Ektron (A .net CMS)  I'm attempting to turn it into an MVC4 / Webforms hybrid.
As far as I can tell I have everything MVC4 needs installed correctly but when I try to hit the default Home controller I get the classic

```
[InvalidOperationException: The view 'Index' or its master was not found or no view engine supports the searched locations. The following locations were searched:
~/Views/home/Index.aspx
~/Views/home/Index.ascx
~/Views/Shared/Index.aspx
~/Views/Shared/Index.ascx
~/Views/home/Index.cshtml
~/Views/home/Index.vbhtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.cshtml
~/Views/Shared/Index.vbhtml]
```

I installed MVC4 using NuGet and by copying over the default controllers, view and associated App_Start and Global.asax files from a default MVC4 application.  I also installed WebAPI which is working fine (so that tells me routing does seems to be working correctly, i.e. I can go to API/Values and get the default values api data back just fine).

The site is installed as a main website, i.e. not as a sub site or sub application.

I initially thought maybe there was an issue with the handlers section as Ektron (our CMS) has a ton of handlers it adds but have torn the web.config apart and can't find any problems in there.  I even tried replacing it with the one from the default MVC4 application and got the same error.
Note, I did have to change one section the default web.config and in my custom one.
When I have this section in there:

```
      <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-2.1.10.0" newVersion="2.1.10.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

I get the error

```
Could not load file or assembly 'System.Net.Http, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a' or one of its dependencies. The located assembly's manifest definition does not match the assembly reference. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x80131040)
```

I looked at the assembly details for that DLL and found it was version 4.0.0.0 so I changed that section to say

```
      <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity name="System.Net.Http" publicKeyToken="b03f5f7f11d50a3a" culture="neutral" />
    <bindingRedirect oldVersion="0.0.0.0-4.0.0.0" newVersion="4.0.0.0" />
  </dependentAssembly>
```

Which fixes that error and as far as I can tell is OK but again, I'm left with the above problem of the views not being found.

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: What is the actual path to your view?

Answer (score 0):

OK, I feel dumb.

@SLaks simple question helped me find the answer.

We have a rather complicated build system.  It combines the Ektron base code project, which is a web site not a project, with our main project and class libraries into output directories, in this case /debug which is where my IIS is pointing.  There's several steps involved, including converting our web project back into a web site during "build" (don't ask, it's a pain but speeds up build times a ton).
Anyway, we only copy certain file types out and .cshtml wasn't in the list, so yeah, no view folder in the output debug directory . . .